# How to make monthly subscription payments with paypal php rest api

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I want to make monthly subscription payment with paypal php rest api. Is it possible with rest api. If yes then please describe how can I achieve that. Also after successful subscription how can I cancel the subscription via Api. Also how can update the DB if subscription payment is failed.

Comment: where are using restApi?

Comment: X-Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74844057/367456

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create a subscription payment with the Paypal API.

First of all you need to create a product with the catalogue api:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/catalog-products/v1/#products_create

You have to create a product regardless what you are selling (physical goods or services)

The you will use the subscriptions api to create plans that are linked to the created product:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_create

Obviously a product can have multiple plans with different pricing or billing cycle

Finally you can integrate the Smart Payment buttons to your checkout form to allow users to subscribe to a plan:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#4-create-a-subscription

You can read the currently complete guide of paypal subscription integration here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/

After a subscription is created it can be canceled via the subscription api:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_cancel

Answer (score -1):

I don't remember how to create the recurring payment with Paypal, but as far as I know, canceling it is not possible *via* their api.

On our website, we have to tell the users to cancel their subscription on paypal's website.

Comment: No Paypal support Subscription via REST API, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/